# graphql-shield as 'makeProcessSchemaPlugin' in Postgraphile

Tags: postgraphile

[Tried postgrphile example](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-process-schema-plugin/) but not sure where mistake were done?

I am trying to implement graphql-shield as a plugin

```
    middlewarePlugin = makeProcessSchemaPlugin((schema: typeof GraphQLSchema) => {
        return applyMiddleware(schema, permissions);
    });
```

permission.ts

```
const { rule, shield } = require("graphql-shield");

const isAuthenticated = rule()((parent: any, args: any,  user: any ) => {
    return user !== null;
});

const permissions = shield({
    Query: {
        viewer: isAuthenticated
    }
});

export = permissions;
```

I import middlewarePlugin as others plugins in postgraphile:

```
  appendPlugins: [
            myClass.myPlugin,
            myClass.jsonPlace,
            myClass.middlewarePlugin
        ],
```

crash log:

> | A serious error occurred when building the initial schema. Exiting because `retryOnInitFail` is not set. Error details:
> graphql    |
> graphql    | TypeError: Cannot read property 'fragment' of undefined
> graphql    |     at isMiddlewareWithFragment (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/utils.ts:25:17)
> graphql    |     at Object.isMiddlewareFunction (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/utils.ts:33:10)
> graphql    |     at Object.validateMiddleware (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/validation.ts:9:7)
> graphql    |     at addMiddlewareToSchema (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/middleware.ts:33:27)
> graphql    |     at normalisedMiddlewares.reduceRight.schema.schema (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/middleware.ts:91:11)
> graphql    |     at Array.reduceRight ()
> graphql    |     at applyMiddlewareWithOptions (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/middleware.ts:80:77)
> graphql    |     at applyMiddleware (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphql-middleware/src/middleware.ts:132:10)
> graphql    |     at hook (/home/node/app/resolvers/test.resolver.ts:254:16)
> graphql    |     at SchemaBuilder.applyHooks (/home/node/app/node_modules/graphile-build/src/SchemaBuilder.js:398:20)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, looks like postgraphile and graphql-shield doesn't work at the moment.
https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-middleware/issues/369

Comment: Yeah, I learned that the type of middleware postgraphile expects is a little different from graphql-middleware. I ended up with a custom solution using `makeWrapResolversPlugin`. It isn't perfect yet but it's also pretty simple to implement, would be happy to share if this is still an issue. Essentially, think of `makeWrapResolversPlugin` as a replacement for `graphql-shield`

Comment: Yeah, any solution to this one would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of middleware postgraphile expects is a little different from graphql-middleware. Instead of downloading `graphql-middleware` and `graphql-shield` and trying to get them to work with postgraphile, I ended up writing my own "shield" with [makeWrapResolversPlugin](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/make-wrap-resolvers-plugin/). Example:

```
const filter = (ctx) => {
  // Only attempting to do auth for non-root things, because
  // with postgraphile, all the data gets fetched at the root
  if (ctx.scope.isRootMutation || ctx.scope.isRootQuery) {
    // return this to make it available to the wrapper function
    return ctx.scope.fieldName
  }
  // return null to not wrap this non-root resolver
  return null
}

const wrapper = (fieldName) => 
  async (resolve, source, args, context) => {
    // Unless we're doing createUser, do an auth check

    // 
    if (fieldName === "createUser") return resolve()

    const isAuthenticated = await getIsAuthenticated(context)

    // 
    if (isAuthenticated) return resolve()

    throw new Error("Unauthorized");
  }

const Permissions = makeWrapResolversPlugin(filter, wrapper)
```